# A mismatch in the number of items to be reviewed

Tags: bug, review-lists

Interestingly, the number of items displayed in the header usually does not match the sum of numbers of the individual review queues.  See the screenshot, taken a few minutes ago:

[image]

Why is this so?  I don't know if there is any connection, but I've noticed this after reaching 10k.

**Udpate [sic!]:** thanks to [ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube), I've found this post on meta.SE:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/180128

and its followup:
[Modulate the review notification's color to reflect changes, or make it dismissible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230833/modulate-the-review-notifications-color-to-reflect-changes-or-make-it-dismissi)

Comment: Note also that there are many cases where different areas of the UI display the same data, but the display is refreshed at different rates (some through Ajax, some on page load), so sometimes the answer is, more annoyingly: caching.